# What do the flags at the pod races represent?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In *[Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/)* during the podracing scene, just before the race begins a small number of flag-bearers make their way across the screen, one of which is C-3PO.

[image: View facing the podracers about to start; Sebulba's distinctive racer is prominent on the right. The flag bearers walk ceremonially in a line across in front of the podracers.]
*Flag-bearers during podrace.*

When considering the flags, at first thought, I would think them to be planet flags or something along those lines. However, upon looking up Tatooine's flag it's not even close to the same as what C-3PO's carrying.

[image: Close-up of C-3PO (without his shiny outer armour) carrying Anakin's blue-on-white flag]
*C-3PO carrying a flag for Team Ani.*

[image: The official flag of Tatooine has a light brown field, with a darker green-brown stripe on the left side and across the middle forming a sideways T; two yellow circles, the larger on the left, occupy the middle of the flag, centre-aligned to the crossing line.]
*Official flag of Tatooine.*

**If the flags being carried don't represent the planet from which the racer associates with, then, what *do* they represent?**

Comment: i believe they're racer team flags, just like in modern f1.  could also represent a cartel, comission, federation or trade corporation that represents it. http://e2.365dm.com/14/09/16-9/30/formula-1-grand-prix-italy-italian-atmosphere-crowd-fans-flags-monza-podium_3199881.jpg?20140904173702

Comment: You've answered your own question with the caption for the C-3PO image: they're team flags.

Comment: @Charles Are you sure you made your edit about the flag not being official?

Comment: @ToddSewell I obtained the updated image from [Star Wars Wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:TatooineFlag.jpg). If this isn't accurate to the actual flag, please suggest an edit.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The flags are intended to identify the racer to the crowd and to advertise the racer's sponsor/s.

> *As racers enter the arena, flagbearers march with them. **Flags are
> decorated with heraldry, symbols or colours associated with the racer.
> The flags can also represent a sponsor who funds the team in order to
> gain local or galactic recognition.***
>
> <sub><sup>[*Star Wars: The Visual Encyclopedia*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Encyclopedia)</sup></sub>
>
> [image: Table of 18 pod racer flags, labeled for each racer. Anakin's blue-on-white flag is in the upper left and Sebulba's orange/yellow/black flag is in the lower left]

and

> *Standard bearers, each carrying **a flag that identified the pilot and
> sponsor**, marched along, forming a colorful line in front of the
> assembly of Podracers. Overhead, the twin suns of Tatooine shone down
> with a bright, hungry glare.*
>
> <sub><sup>*Star Wars: The Phantom Menace* - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

---

You can see the home planets of the various racers listed below. Even though several racers are from the same planet or planetary system (Anakin and Ody Mandrell from Tatooine, Aldar Beedo and Elan Mak from the Ploo system) all of the racers have largely dissimilar flags which means that it's hard to draw any specific judgements but it would seem likely that plain planetary flags are mostly reserved for those without powerful sponsors.

[image: Tables. of the finish placings and the number of laps completed for non-finishers. Each table lists the home system by the racer's name; the flags of each appear in order horizontally beneath the tables.]
<sub><sup>[The Official Star Wars Fact File #26](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_26)</sup></sub>

Comment: So do you have an explanation of the flag?  Does it represent Ani?  Watto?  Qui-Gon? Slavery? Freedom? The Jedi?  The Force? George Lucas? Some random set designer/dresser?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - I can't find any explanation for the flag. If I do, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: It probably doesn't represent anything more than horse jockey patterns do.

Comment: "Elan Mak's flag," eh? Do you suppose it's a coincidence or named after Elon Musk?

Comment: @Kevin - Complete coincidence, I would imagine. In 1999 he was still working in Silicon Valley; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eb3pmifEZ44

Comment: @Kevin: Hmmm, I wonder whether it would be Tesla or SpaceX that would have built that pod?

Comment: Also, Dud Bolt is a very very funny name for a pod racer.

Comment: I'm not sure of other instances, but Anakin's clone wars starfighter has the same colorings http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Azure_Angel so it seems to represent Anakin rather than any sponsor.

Comment: @JeremyFrench - Noting that, I've created a [second answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179185/20774) that you might find interesting.

Comment: Looks like the prop makers just phoned in some of those flag designs. `Designer 1:` "Oh, crud, we have to come up with 4 more designs before the end of the day!" `Designer 2:` "Don't worry, you've got that one with a single body color and a couple of stripes. Just change the colors and make the stripes wave a bit differently, nobody will notice. Job done!"

Answer (score 32):

I can't find it explicitly stated in canon, but in the video game [*Star Wars: Episode I Racer*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_Racer) the flags are treated as vehicle/team flags. For example, you can see them in the background when selecting a vehicle/team:

[image: Anakin's team flag]
<sup>Source: https://r.mprd.se/media/images/51725-Star_Wars_Episode_1_Racer_(PAL)-1.jpg</sup>

[image: Sebulba's team flag]
<sup>Source: https://r.mprd.se/media/images/51725-Star_Wars_Episode_1_Racer_(PAL)-2.jpg</sup>

The game is Legends but was released by [LucasArts](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/LucasArts) so the game's use of the flags is likely the intended purpose from the film. Additionally, each flag tends to match the paint scheme for the vehicle it is paired with.

Comment: That game brings back memories!

Comment: Quite possibly the best racing game I’ve ever played. The dual-controller thing (each joystick controlling one of the podracer’s two engines) was *awesome*.

Comment: @KRyan wait whaaaaaat. I've been playing this recently and hadn't noticed that. The sticks seriously control different engines? Woah.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald AFAIR you need to enter a cheat, like RRJABA or something and you can plug in two controllers to give each stick an engine. disclaimer its been about 20 years since I last played. edit: RRDUAL is the cheat, RRJABA is for godmode

Comment: There is an open source port of the game here: https://github.com/OpenSWE1R/openswe1r

Comment: For what it's worth, there were two different podracer games that were released. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_Racer was released for N64 (and other systems). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Racer_Revenge was released for PS2. I love both of these games.

Answer (score 15):

### In Universe

With regard to the specific question of Anakin's flag, it would appear that it was **self-designed by Anakin and inspired by Padmé**.

When we first see Anakin's pod, it has no paintjob and no livery.

[image: Anakin's pod is bare, dusty and unpainted.]

He meets with Padmé and shortly afterwards the blue paintwork is applied to the pod and a flag designed.

[image: The pod is now shiny, silvery and has a blue logo and stripes painted on it. The logo matches his flag which is also shown.]

Later, during the clone wars Anakin customises his first (and second) Aethersprite ships with the same livery as his podracer and names them for his secret wife, the [**Azure Angel**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Azure_Angel).

[image: Blue and white livery of Anakin's ship]

> To show his love for the ship, we had to come up with a name that also
> reflected his love for the one person he cherished more than life
> itself, Padmé. It then dawned on me - Angel. And **since the colors of
> the ship were based off of the bluish colors of Anakin's Podracer, it
> was a given that it had to be a blue Angel, or something like it.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Leland Chee: The Blue Angels/Star Wars connection](http://web.archive.org/web/20090301020109/http://blogs.starwars.com:80/holocron/16)</sup></sub>

All of this is a bit circular until you see what Padme was wearing when Anakin first met her. **She's literally wearing the same shade of blue as the paint on his pod and the same blue as the paint on his fighter.**

[image: Comparison of the blue shade of Anakin's flag from the pod race and the sleeve of Padme's tunic that's she's wearing when she and Anakin meet.]

---

### Out of universe

The [*Art of Star Wars: The Phantom Menace*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace) factbook describes the blue motif on Anakin's flag (and livery on the podracer itself) as having been inspired and designed by Lucas personally. They represent a similar design to one on a sports car he once owned. The orange symbol on the flag and topside of the racer is a *"Hutt sanctioning body"* logo.

Comment: Awesome spot about the blue she was wearing.

Comment: @Valorum After reading this response, it came to my mind that Anakin also gives Padme [a necklace made from japor snippet](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HsYcrAnk17c/hqdefault.jpg), and, upon examining it, it appears to also have this design; that being, four lines/paths that come from each corner to then converge at the center, which contains a square. It could easily be argued that [this design is similar to the simple targeting systems used in the T-65 X-wings](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/6/6d/CMD.png/revision/latest?cb=20130305230019). How cool!